# Powershell Script not recognising ForEach-Object as a valid cmdlet

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

I have writen a powershell script to make ammendments to Active Directory.
I am Getting a funny error.
Here is the script.

```
    #imports the module active directory if it isn't there.
function add-ADmodule()
            {
            $modules = Get-Module | Where-Object{$_.Name -like "*ActiveDirectory*"}

            if($modules -eq $null)
                {
                Import-Module ActiveDirectory
                }
            }

#import the data file
$user_csv = import-csv C:\temp\users.csv

#makes the ammendments to the AD object
function ammend-ADUsers($user_csv)
    {#this is the loop to make ammendments to each object
        $users_csv|ForEach-Object`
                {
                #assigns each user's AD object to a variable
                $user_object = get-aduser -filter * `
                                          -Properties mail |`
                              Where-Object{$_.mail -like $_."Email Address"}

                #ammends the ad object in the above variable
                set-aduser -Identity $user_object `
                           -OfficePhone $_."Office Number" `
                           -MobilePhone $_."Mobile Number" `
                           -StreetAddress $_."Street" `
                           -City $_."City" `
                           -PostalCode $_."PostCode"    
                }
    }


#this is the main part of the code where it gets executed

add-ADmodule
Write-Verbose "Active Directory Module Added"

ammend-ADUsers($user_csv)
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
PS C:\Users\admin> C:\Scripts\ammend-aduser.ps1
ForEach-Object : The term 'ForEach-Object' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Scripts\ammend-aduser.ps1:18 char:20
+         $users_csv|ForEach-Object`
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ForEach-Object:String) [], Com  
  mandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I am not not sure what could be causing this error or why it is happening.

Comment: Watch out for this - `ammend-ADUsers($user_csv)` - that's not good PowerShell cmdlet argument syntax, you should use `ammend-ADUsers $user_csv`. Your code works, but not the same way as other languages - it will break if you try to use it for two params like `ammend-ADUsers($user_csv, $param2)` and will pass them both as an array to the first parameter instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is because you have not put a space between the cmdlet and the backtick character, but it would be better to not use a backtick and instead just keep the opening curly brace `{` on the same line:

```
$users_csv|ForEach-Object {
```

You also don't need a backtick after a pipe character. You might want to also consider using splatting instead of backticks to improve your formatting (backticks are generally discouraged as they can be hard to see and easy to use improperly). I suggest the following revision:

```
$users_csv | ForEach-Object {
        #assigns each user's AD object to a variable
        $user_object = Get-ADUser -filter * -Properties mail |
                       Where-Object{$_.mail -like $_."Email Address"}

        $Props = @{
             Identity = $user_object
             OfficePhone = $_."Office Number"
             MobilePhone = $_."Mobile Number"
             StreetAddress = $_."Street"
             City = $_."City"
             PostalCode = $_."PostCode"    
        }
        #ammends the ad object in the above variable
        Set-ADUser @Props
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this Mark. I am not familiar with splatting, can you point me in the direction of a good guide for it?

Comment: Sure, check this out: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675931.aspx. As shown above, its a case of building a hashtable of the parameters and settings you want them to have, then sending that hashtable to the cmdlet with the `@` character instead of `$`.